# Pass error element to kendo dataSource

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

I'm using one dataSource for multiple kendo elements. Is there a simple way of how can I pass error element to dataSource, where error can be shown if it occurs?

```
var countryDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: function (options) {     
      $.ajax({
        url: utils.createUrl("codelist/GetCountries"),
        success: function (result) {
          // notify the data source that the request succeeded
          options.success(result);
        },
        error: function (response) {
          // notify the data source that the request failed
          // that.displayError(alertContainer, response.status.toString() + "[" + response.statusText + "]");
          options.error(response);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});

$("[data-id=loadingLocationCountry]").kendoDropDownList({
  autoBind: false,
  // how can I pass error element e.g. countryDataSource($(errorElement)))
  dataSource: countryDataSource 
});    

$("[data-id=unloadingLocationCountry]").kendoDropDownList({
  autoBind: false,
  dataSource: countryDataSource
});
```

I came up with only this solution, but new dataSource **is created for each usage (new instance)**

```
var countryDataSource = function(errorContainer) {
   return new kendo.data.DataSource({
      ....
      error: function (response) {
      // notify the data source that the request failed
      that.displayError(that.errorContainer, response.status.toString() + "[" + response.statusText + "]");
      options.error(response);
    }
   });
}

$("[data-id=loadingLocationCountry]").kendoDropDownList({
  ..
  dataSource: countryDataSource($("[data-id=loadingCountryErrorContainer]")) 
});
```

Comment: just curious, why do you want to do that? and i dont think it is a good idea to share same datasource, except you instantiate them twice and 1 for each. since any sort/filter happen to the ds will reflected in both dropdown

Comment: @himawan_r didn't think of that, since I don't need that functionality. Better than, that for each kendo widget to use its own dataSource - return new kendo.data.DataSource + I can pass error element. Thanx for this.